# Decimales se redondean hacia arriba Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, numberformat, decimal

Tengo un numero con 8 decimales, donde se me presenta el error que el ultimo decimal se redondea hacia arriba, cosa que no quiero que ocurra y que tampoco he dado ninguna instruccion para que esto ocurra.

numero inicial = 98015469.97990022
numero al imprimirse 98015469.97990023

```js
const numberToTest = 98015469.97990022

console.log("numberToTest: ", numberToTest)
```

Necesito que el numero se muestre tal como lo declaro inicialmente osea 98015469.97990022

Comment: Cual es tu objetivo final? solo imprimirlo y que se muestre tal cual?

Comment: si quiero se tome tal cual el numero que le ingreso

Comment: Vas a realizar operaciones con esos números? Estás haciendo cálculos que necesitan, en realidad, precisión de 8 decimales? Son geodirecciones? Si sólo necesitas mostrarlos, como dijo christian, string es suficiente. Puedes ver [esta respuesta de SO en inglés.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: Eso ya es un número de por si, no te hace falta nada.  Si lo quieres mostrar tal cual sin el redondeo y como string puedes probar con: `numberagain = numberToTest.toPrecision(17).substring(0, 17)` pero si lo vuelves a pasar a número con parseFloat(numberagain) te volverá a pasar lo mismo. El motivo ni idea.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente el concepto matematematico esta bien así, si deseas hacer calculos no vas a tener ningun inconveniente con el resultado, si lo que te molesta es que se aproxime al imprimirlo como tal el tipo de  datos debe ser string, es decir que si lo traes de un input debe ser input text, si tu campo en base de datos es double debes tenerlo en varchar.

```
const numberToTest = '98015469.97990022'

console.log("numberToTest: ", numberToTest)
```

ya si quieres hacer calculos

```
let minumero=parseFloat(numberToTest);
```

Comment: necesito que sea un numero si o si, si uso el parse float lo  redondea de nuevo hacia arriba y quedamos en la misma